# unable to make equilateral triangle with 2 dimension array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

i am preparing my self for the interview.
I have to make a equilateral triangle Using 7X7 2D array.

I tried the below code but i am confused like what should i do in my code so that i can make a equilateral triangle?

```
    package learn.basic.corejava;

public class ArrayExample {


    public void two_equilateral_D()
    {
        System.out.println("Demonstrating 2D 3X3 Equal trngle");
        int twoD[][]=new int[7][7];
        int i,j,k=0;

        for(i=0;i<7;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<7;j++)
            {       
                twoD[i][j]=k>9?0:k; 
                k++;
            }   
        }

        for(i=0;i<7;i++)
        {  
              for(j=i+3;j<7;j++) {
             System.out.print(twoD[i][j]+"   ");   
              }
            System.out.println("");
        }

    }  

    public static void main(String args[] )
    {
        ArrayExample obj=new ArrayExample();
        //System.out.println("Average value of the array="+obj.calculate_average());
        obj.two_equilateral_D();

    }
}
```

But this code gives me output like

```
Demonstrating 2D 3X3 Equal trngle
3   4   5   6   
0   0   0   
0   0   
0
```

**Desired output like this**

[image]

Comment: Can you better explain what the expected output should be?

Comment: @plz wait i am preparing the output ...

Comment: @KevinDiTraglia I updated desired output

Comment: To make an indented row, just add spaces before you start with the numbers. What other part are you confused by?

Comment: @alexis sir i updated desired output ,what logic i have to implement so that i can solve this problem by myself

Comment: Maybe http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle would help. What *I'm* confused about is, what kind of interview is this? You seem to be asking for help with an elementary programming problem.

Comment: PS. You radically changed the desired output (though the original output didn't make much sense, frankly). People don't like that, it makes earlier answers irrelevant.

Comment: @alexis Agreed. This is annoying.

Comment: @alexis sorry about that. I am learning it to get job. All my colligues  placed in good company but i am still in one place. I am preparing for job like this http://tinyurl.com/msbdjhm

Comment: @Danny Now, is your question about how to initialize your matrix or how to display it?

Comment: @Danny Java EE is quite a bit more complicated than this problem. Your problem here is more programming-related than Java related.

Comment: @Joffrey then what you recommend me? i went for many interview they said i am weak in "core java" , thats why from yesterday i started reading core java once again

Comment: Good luck, but based on your question you might not be ready for this job yet. Maybe you need more work on fundamental skills like how to describe and break down a problem; not just coding practice.

Comment: @alexis is there any books/site which tells me like how to learn `fundamental skills like how to describe and break down a problem` as you said?

Comment: Your curriculum should have covered that, so I'd look at your own course materials! But there are plenty of such lists on the web and here on SO. I don't have one in mind, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To approach your problem, you should start by breaking it down into two smaller sub-problems:

1. Generate the desired triangular matrix of values (it's called
   [Pascal's triangle,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle) among other things).
2. Display the values nicely.

Each of the problems is fairly straightforward by itself. Try your hand at them and come back if you need help.

Answer (score 0):

I think the special condition (the hard part) shouldn't be in the loop condition, but in a new condition inside the nested loop.

1. You need to iterate over the whole matrix, instead of limiting the nested loop (with variable `j`).
2. Inside the loop, add an `if()` statement to check whether you want to display the value or just a space. This condition is what you should work on.

The code should look like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
        if (condition) {
            System.out.print(twoD[i][j]+"   ");   
        } else {
            System.out.print("    "); // note the extra space here to make up for a number
        }
    }
    System.out.println("");
}
```

---

EDIT: You radically changed your question, there is now two problems:

1. You have to initialize your matrix with Pascal's Triangle values.
2. The output you now posted is not a console output, you'll have to make choices as to where to put the spaces, and how to deal with 2-digit numbers. The easiest is to make every cell take 2 characters (either a space and a digit, or 2 digits).

Comment: sir i updated my question with desired output, please have a look and recommend me

Comment: @Danny I saw your expected output, that's why I wrote this piece of code. You have to tune the condition properly to have it `true` when `i` and `j` refer to a location in your triangle, and false otherwise.

Comment: i have not done - vote.  i updated my question can you help me by giving a  logic. I  need to learn fast.

Comment: Oh ok you changed your desired output, that's something different then... let me think

Comment: The output you now posted is not a console output, you'll have to make choices as to where to put the spaces, and how to deal with 2-digit numbers. The easiest is to make every cell take 2 characters (either a space and a digit, or 2 digits). See my comment below your question btw.

Answer (score -1):

in the second nested loop

```
for(i=0;i<7;i++)
{  
      for(j=i+3;j<7;j++) {
     System.out.print(twoD[i][j]+"   ");   
      }
    System.out.println("");
}
```

you are removing any values beyond index 3 which is why you are only going to 4 numbers instead of 7

After writing to the 7x7 array use

```
int num=0;
for(i=1;i<7;i++)
{  
    num=0;
    for(j=7;j>7-i;j--) 
    {
        System.out.print(twoD[i][j]+"   ");  
        System.out.print(twoD[i][num]+"   ");
        num++;
    }
    System.out.println("");
}
```

This should give the desired output

Comment: sir i updated my question with desired output, please have a look and recommend me